# Drawing directed graph using power point and latex

Tags: latex

Is anyone aware of a way to draw something like the following in latex?
I bet `tikzpicture` can allow to achieve that, but can anyone show me a simple example?

[image]

Credit to the author: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Accountalive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun a version in `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
 arrow style=tikz,
 >={latex} 
]
    \arrow[rd,shift left] \arrow[rd,<-,shift right,-] & & & & & & \\
    & \text{\textbullet} \arrow[rrd,shift left]\arrow[rrd,shift right,<-] \arrow[dd,shift left,"prev(e)",teal] \arrow[dd,shift right,<-] & & & & & \arrow[ld,shift left] \arrow[ld,shift right,-] \\
    & & & \text{\textbullet} \arrow[rr,shift left] \arrow[rr,shift right,<-]& & \text{\textbullet} \arrow[ld,shift left]\arrow[ld,shift right,<-,"next(e)",swap,green,near end] & \\
    & \text{\textbullet} \arrow[rrr,shift left,"e",blue]\arrow[rrr,shift right,<-,"twin(e)",swap,orange] & & & \text{\textbullet} \arrow[rd,shift left,-]\arrow[rd,shift right,<-] & & \\
    & & & & & ~ & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]